# How to select which job should run in Spring Batch + Spring Rest API

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to implement to 2 Spring Batch jobs which will run when an endpoint is consumed.  Since JobLauncher method is the same for both of them, how can you select which one is going to be executed?

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private Job job;

@RequestMapping(
        value = "/expired",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        params = {"expireDate"}
)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO expiredJob(@RequestParam(value = "expireDate") String expireDate) throws BusinessException, Exception {

    if (!DateValidator.isDateFormatValid(expireDate)) {
        throw new BusinessException(ExceptionCodes.DATE_FORMAT_ERROR);
    }
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("expireDate", expireDate).toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

    ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();

    return responseDTO;
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = "/lucky",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO rciplusJob() throws BusinessException, Exception {

    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

    ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();

    return responseDTO;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in this way like I do.

I assume you have a spring batch job config for each job. e.g.:

```
@Bean(name = "job1")
public Job job1() {
    return jobBuilders.get("job1")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1())
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

and the same for job2:

```
@Bean(name = "job2")
public Job job2() {
    return jobBuilders.get("job2")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step2())
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

Now in your controller you just autowire both jobs:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("job1")
private Job job1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("job2")
private Job job2;
```

To start each of them you can do it like this:

```
final JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But when I do it this way, the job starts automatically. I have the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation in each of my JobConfig and batch.job.enabled: false in my properties file but it still launches it

Comment: The property is `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant that, forgot to write the spring.

Comment: very good answer, when running SpringBoot app I usually don't like to get the app context manually & get the beans for execution, this must be the proper way & it's keeping the abstractions of SpringBoot context away from our source code, Perfect answer for the use case!